# Redirect from login page to home page

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help with an assignment I'm stuck on please. I have a login.html page and when i enter the correct username and password I want it to redirect to my home.html page. My code for this is:

```
function checkdetails()

{

    var name = "", password = "";
    name = form1.txtusername.value
    password = form1.txtpassword.value

    if (name == "Shauna" && password =="8nss")
{   
    window.alert("Both right")
    location = "home.html"

    form1.txtusername.value=""
    form1.txtpassword.value=""
}
}
```

I know its the location="home.html" that is wrong but can't find anywhere thats providing me with an alternative unless i open up a new window which i don't want.

Thanks!!

Comment: Missing a lot of semi-colons.... `;` ... that should have been covered on day 1

Comment: Don't worry @EatPeanutButter JS will add it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use :

```
window.location.replace("home.html");
```

But because you're using form the better way is to add submit button and submit your form to the action you want :

```
<form action="home.html">

    <input type="submit" value="Go to Home" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This one worked! it must have been a problem with the form action. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way of doing it that will be faster and easier:

```
window.location.assign('home.html');
```